How to resolve GitHub access issues in IntelliJ?
I was practicing creating a Git repository with IntelliJ, but it is giving this error (note: I have already connected my GitHub account to IntelliJ via token).
"Cannot loadinformation for githup.com/username123:Request response:
Acess to this site has been restricted. If you belive this is an error
please contact suport github"

how to resolve this?

It is a known problem caused by a security issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-156496.
Please update IntelliJ to the latest version - 2024.1.3: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and re-issue the GitHub authentication token.

Updating may fix this problem.

